# How to connect these two and create a crease between them?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

This is difficult to explain so im open to any edits on those post. I'm trying to create a pinch between the bottom of this arm rest and the line design on this wall. I've tried using the pinch sculpting tool but it doesnt give the desired results.

[image]

[image]

I've also tried to extrude the bottom edges to the line design but it fails to work, giving me this:

[image]

I've also tried bridge edge loop, to no avail. Im open to any idea.